# What wire size to be used for Peltier cooling

Tags: wire, peltier, cooling, gauge

I'm making a project with three Peltier in parallel (12V & 6A) each (TEC 12706) for cooling.

I would just like to know the wire size to be used in (AWG or mm2), for running project smoothly.

Comment: There are online tables and calculators to help you decide.

Comment: if you can run them in series instead you'll require much thinner cable, which might be cheaper than a 36v PSU vs a 12v PSU...

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the DC wire size you need to use this:
A = **(2LIϱ)/V**.

V — Voltage drop(V).
I — Current(A).
ϱ — Resistivity of the conductor(Ω×m).
L — Wire Length(m).
A — Wire size(m^2).

Lets do some math shall we:
you are running 3 Peltiers in parallel and each uses 6A so you have to multiply 6A with 3, 3x6=**18A**.
Voltage will stay the same(**12V**).
you wanna run **5m** of wire.
your wanna use copper wire, resistivity is typically **1.68x10-8** at **20 C**.
max Voltage drop = **5%**.

(2×5×18×1.68×10⁻⁸)/(0.05×12) = ~0,000005m² or ~5mm² or ~**2.5mm**.
correct me if I'm wrong.
for really short runs the voltage drop isn't as important(can be seen in the table)
there are also table's that you can use to check the required wire size:

[image]

*[Image Source](https://quinled.info/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/gaugetable_1.png)*

Comment: The voltage does matter. The table is calculated for 5% drop at 24V which is 1.2V. But at 12V, that same 1.2V drop is 10%. So heavier wire is needed to bring down the drop to 5% at 12V.

Comment: For the question "will it overheat?" the operating voltage doesn't matter, only heating caused by I2R losses in the cable.  Where the operating voltage matters is for efficiency concerns.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt, as per table - 2.5mm2 wire is needed till 5m, right !!!

Comment: @Justme i was awake for too long and had my project mind going on, i will edit this, thanks you.